# Grails: Perform a second search on the results of a criteria.list

Tags: grails, hibernate-criteria

I have the following model:

```
class Post {
  int id;
  String comment;
  static belongsTo = [
    category_id:Category,
    author_id:Author
  ];
}
```

I wish to create the following Query: Find the LATEST post (by id) of each author, THEN only return the post if they are of a certain category X.

This is how far I have got so far:

```
def cat = Category.findByID(x); // Not yet used

def c = Post.createCriteria();
def results = c.list {
  projections {
    groupProperty("author_id", "myid")
    max("id", "version")
  }
}

def posts = results?.collect{Post.read(it[0])}
```

The temptation is to add `like("categorie_id", cat)` just before `projections`.

HOWEVER, this results in getting the last post of each author RELATED to category X.

I need: the latest post of each author IF it BELONGS TO category X.

In other word, I want to know if the latest post of each author is of category x.

I think that in order to do this I need to perform a second search on the results of the first, but I have no idea how to do this.

Any suggestions?

Thank You,

Chopo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't define an `id` field unless it's different from the one that GORM adds for you - it adds a Long id by default, so yours isn't needed. Also, your `belongsTo` names are very nonstandard - the `_id` suffix should be removed. And what's the deal with all of those semicolons ;)

Given this domain class:

```
class Post {
   String comment
   static belongsTo = [
      category: Category,
      author: Author
   ]
}
```

Then you can get the most recent posts for each author for a specified category with this HQL query (I have no idea how to do it with a Criteria query):

```
def category = ...

def posts = Post.executeQuery(
   'select p from Post p where id in (' +
      'select max(p.id) from Post p ' +
      'where p.category=:category group by p.author.id)',
   [category: category])
```

Comment: Dosn't that only return one result? (I will test it tomorrow morning/ dev pc is turned off) I want a list of posts who are the last article of any author and fall within a specific category

Comment: btw, the semicolons aka hiper-semicolonophilia is a well known psychological condition resulting from years of c++/Java, but I'm working on it ;-)

Comment: I updated the answer - now it returns the most recent post for each author if there is one for the specified category.

Comment: I think the `where p.category=:category` needs to be in the outer select instead of the inner.